# Jquery DataTable issue On ServerSide Processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

My scripts are Here:

```
 <link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

My Jquery Code is Here:

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
                //"width":540,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                scrollY: 265,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sUrl": "media/language/de_DE.txt",
                    "sZeroRecords": "There are no records that match your search criterion",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
                    "sInfo": "Displaying _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/LoadData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",

                    "dataFilter": function(data){
                   var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                   json.recordsTotal = json.recordsTotal
                   json.recordsFiltered = json.recordsFiltered;
                   json.data = json.data;
                   return JSON.stringify( json ); 
                  }

                },
                "columns": [

                     {
                         "data": " ", "autoWidth": true, 'sortable': false, "mRender":
                          function (value, AddedOn, mData, type, row) {
                                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="employeeIdsToDelete" id="' + mData.ID + '" class="call-checkbox" value="' + mData.ID + '" />';
                                                                       }
                     },

                     {
                          "data": "Station", "name": "Station", "autoWidth": true, 'render':
                           function (Station, mData, type, row) {
                                     return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + type.ID + "' id='modal1' >"+ type.Station +"</a>";
                                                                 }
                      },
                      {
                          "data": "FlightNo", "name": "Flight No.", "autoWidth": true, 'render':
                            function (FlightNo, mData, type, row) {
                                return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + type.ID + "' id='modal1' >" + type.FlightNo + "</a>";
                                                                   }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "FlightDate", "name": "FlightDate", "autoWidth": true, "type": "date", "render":
                              function (value, FlightDate, mData, type, row) {
                                if (value === null) return "";
                                var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                                var results = pattern.exec(value);
                                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
                                //var d = new Date();
                                var MonthIndex = dt.getMonth();
                                var monthnames = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
                                var imonth = monthnames[MonthIndex];

                                return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + mData.ID + "' id='modal1' >" + dt.getDate() + " " + imonth + " " + dt.getFullYear() + "</a>";
                                                                                }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "PaxNo", "name": "No. of Pax", "autoWidth": true, 'render':
                              function (No_Of_Passengers, mData, type, row) {
                                return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + type.ID + "' id='modal1' >" + type.No_Of_Passengers + "</a>";
                                                                             }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "StatusDescription", "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true, 'render':
                              function (StatusDescription, mData, type, row) {
                                  return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + type.ID + "' id='modal1' >" + type.StatusDescription + "</a>";
                                                                             }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "TextMsg", "name": "LDM", "autoWidth": true, 'render': function (TextMsg, mData, type, row) {


                                return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + type.ID + "'id='modal1' >" + type.TextMsg + "</a>";
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "AddedOn", "name": "AddedOn", "autoWidth": true, "type": "date",


                            "render": function (value, AddedOn, mData, type, row) {
                                if (value === null) return "";
                                var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                                var results = pattern.exec(value);
                                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
                                //var d = new Date();
                                var MonthIndex = dt.getMonth();
                                var monthnames = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
                                var imonth = monthnames[MonthIndex];

                                return "<a href='/Home/EditEmployee?id=" + mData.ID + "' id='modal1' >" + dt.getDate() + " " + imonth + " " + dt.getFullYear() + "</a>";
                                //return (dt.getDate() + " " + imonth + " " + dt.getFullYear());
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": " ", "autoWidth": true, 'sortable': false,


                    "mRender": function (value, AddedOn, mData, type, row) {

                        if (mData.StatusDescription == "Tkt. info. missing")
                        {
                            return "<a href='/Home/Ticket?id=" + mData.ID + "' id='modal2' class='btn btn-primary btn' style='background-color:rgb(255,95,1);border-color:rgb(255,95,1);color:white;' >Miss Tkts</a>";
                        }
                        else {
                            return "Completed";
                        }

                    }
                },
                         {
                             "data": " ", "autoWidth": true, 'sortable': false,


                             "mRender": function (value, AddedOn, mData, type, row) { return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn" style="background-color:rgb(255,95,1);border-color:rgb(255,95,1);color:white;" type="submit" name="Command" value="' + mData.ID + '" > Preview </button>'; }
                         }
                ]
            });
```

And My Controlller Code is Here:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadData()
        {
            cnUCR cn = new cnUCR();
            IEnumerable<usp_FlightsStatusGrid_Result> flightinfo;
            int suserid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
            flightinfo = cn.usp_FlightsStatusGrid(suserid).Where(x => x.StatusID == 5).ToList();
            var idFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["txtStation"]);
           // var StationName = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[0][search][value]").FirstOrDefault();
           // var FlightNo = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[1][search][value]").FirstOrDefault();
            var istatus = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[2][search][value]").FirstOrDefault();
           // var Flightdate = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[3][search][value]").FirstOrDefault();
            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
            //var contactName = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[0][search][value]").FirstOrDefault();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int recordsTotal = 0;
             recordsTotal = flightinfo.Count();
                var data = flightinfo.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

When we run this project MY data not load into table and give me a alert message 
alert message is Here:
DataTables Warning: table id = mytable: Ajax errror. For more information about this error, please see:http://datatales.net/tn/7
Locally its working good but serverside it gives this error

Comment: Can you see the request in the network panel of firebug/developer tools?

Comment: I am using chrome and In developer tool I am getting error  DataTables Warning: table id = mytable: Ajax errror.

Comment: No I have not seen any error in debugger tool.But when we run project alert message comes and says  DataTables Warning: table id = mytable: Ajax errror. For more information about this error, please see:http://datatales.net/tn/7 Locally its working good but serverside it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is how you are mapping each column to a object field.
If you return an array of objects, you should map each column to a object field.
The "data" field in column initialization, should be the name of property.

For example, replace:

```
"data": " ", "autoWidth": true, 'sortable': false,
```

with

```
"data": "ID", "autoWidth": true, 'sortable': false,
```

I think, something like this:

```
var arrayOf_flightinfo = [  { "field1": "a", "field2": "b", "field3": "c" },
                            { "field1": "d", "field2": "e", "field3": "f" },
                            { "field1": "g", "field2": "h", "field3": "i" },
                            { "field1": "j", "field2": "k", "field3": "l" }
                        ];

$('#table_FligthInfo').DataTable({
    aoColumnDefs: [
                { "aTargets": [0], "name": "field1", "title": "Field 1", "data": "field1" },
                { "aTargets": [1], "name": "field2", "title": "Field 2", "data": "field2" },
                { "aTargets": [2], "name": "field3", "title": "Field 3", "data": "field3" }
            ],
    aaData: arrayOf_flightinfo
});
```

I leave some examples about integration between DataTables and .Net on https://github.com/llorentegerman/DataTablesNet, maybe will help you.